# How do I disable caching of a joomla folder using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, joomla

I have a joomla website for a classified site and the advert images are stored in the following directory `/images/adverts/`

I have applied image caching using the `htaccess` file for the site.

Is there a way to prevent caching of the adverts image folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .htaccess in that folder (/images/adverts/) in which you write:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1"
```

Comment: You may also be interested by this post: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/ Specialy the " Improve Site Transfer Speed by Enabling File Caching  " part

Comment: Thanks Haim Confirm I only need that single line of code and nothing else in the .htaccess file that I am to put in the adverts folder